# ROS: How to use rqt_plot to display a field of /geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovarianceMessage?

Tags: ubuntu, ros, rqt

I have a ROS node which publishes a topic `/vslam/pose` which is of type `geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance` message. Running:

```
rostopic type /vslam/pose | rosmsg show
```

gives the following:

```
std_msgs/Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
geometry_msgs/PoseWithCovariance pose
  geometry_msgs/Pose pose
    geometry_msgs/Point position
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
    geometry_msgs/Quaternion orientation
      float64 x
      float64 y
      float64 z
      float64 w
  float64[36] covariance
```

I'd like to use rqt_plot to plot a field (say Point position x). But I tried everything to "call" it in rqt_plot, but it doesn't work, the rqt_plot window shows like it should but the field is not plotted. From `rostopic echo /vslam/pose` I know that it is being published, so everything is working except rqt_plot. Also if I write inside the text-input-field in rqt_plot, like they say in the docs (topic-name/field:field:field): `/vslam/pose/x` or `/vslam/pose/x:y:z` nothing shows.

So basically I'd like to know how to get one of the position fields into rqt_plot. And how correctly refer to these message fields.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [this](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt_plot#Note_for_the_input_value_syntax). It states, that you need the **full** path to your field. In your case that would be:

```
/vslam/pose/pose/pose/position/x:y:z
```